# Left ideals in exterior algebra $\Lambda E$ that aren't right

Tags: abstract-algebra, exterior-algebra

Let $E$ be a vector space. I'm interested in examples of left ideals in exterior algebra $ \Lambda E$ that aren't right ideals.

Comment: if $a,b,c,d$ is a basis of $E$, consider the left  ideal generated by $a+bc$ and check that $(a+bc)d$ is not in.

Comment: @user 8268. Very nice: +1. I encourage you to promote your comment to an answer including some explanation/motivation leading to your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

being encouraged by Georges Elencwajg :)

the simplest example I can come up with is $E$ with basis $a,b,c,d$ and the left ideal generated by $a+bc$; one easily checks that $(a+bc)d\notin I$. How to find it: $\bigwedge E$ is noncommutative, but it is graded-commutative. Ideals generated by $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$-homogeneous elements are thus going to be both-sided. A simple inhomogeneous element which works is $a+bc$.

Comment: I absentmindedly accepted your answer because I thought it will be an example from your comment. But this one doesn't work: $(1-a)(1+a) = 1 + a - a - a^2 = 1$, so the left ideal generated by $1 + a$ is the entire $\Lambda E$...

Comment: @ante.ceperic oh my, it's me who's absent-minded (I'll change it back)

Comment: What is the easiest way to show $(a+bc)d \not \in I$?

Comment: @ante.ceperic: I don't have any smart way. If $x(a+bc)=(a+bc)d$ then $x$ (written in the basis of $\wedge E$) must contain $-d$ to get $ad$, but $bcd$ says it must rather contain $d$.